# Install fpm separately for PHP 5.5.8

Tags: installation, php

I'm doing a manual LAMP setup to learn more about working with the terminal and network configuration, and upon installing the latest version of PHP (5.5.8) I realised that I missed installing fpm. I've been trying to install the extension by itself but I'm not sure how to.
Running php-fpm -v tells me I have version 5.4.17, should fpm's version be the same as PHP in order to work together?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the manual `configure` option, ensure you have set the `--prefix=/path/to/php-5.5.8` and `--enable-fpm`. And you can run `/path/to/php-5.5.8/bin/php` after installation.

Comment: I'm using Brew, and when installing I used brew install php55 but should probably opted for brew install php55 --with-fpm. Is there an easy way of just installing this extension using Brew? brew install php-fpm doesn't work.

Comment: Try php5-fpm? Try checking the available PHP packages.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried that as well. I can't seem to locate any fpm packages when browsing the list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Brew. If it is using packages, you might want to check the repository sources. If it is using `configure` option, add the `--enable-fpm` option to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I figure I reinstall PHP 5.5 and add fpm to the configuration.